# C++: Boost::asio: Wait for asynchronous handler in the same function

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

In `boost::asio`, starting from [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) example, is it possible to wait for the handler in the same function? So something like:

```
void myFunc()
{
    int time = 0;
    socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                                boost::bind(&SSLClient::handle_handshake, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    while(1)
    {
        //hypothetical condition that will become true when async_handshake has finished
        if(handshake_finished) 
        {
            //do something
            break;
        }
        if(time > timeout)
        {
            socket_.cancel();
            break;
        }
        sleep(1);
        time++;
    }
}
```

So I would like to be able to use async calls without having to write a new function to do what's next.

Why I need to do this? Because I'm using QThread, and everything related to the new thread has to be in a single function, `QThread::run()`, and at the end of the function an event loop of Qt has to be executed.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to use an asynchronous call synchronously?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe that's a way to state it... I just need the response to happen in the same function.

Comment: You can, using lambda functions, or coroutines.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I don't think that makes any sense. Are you sure you've understood the Qt constraints correctly? [The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) even contains an example of a long-running and blocking function call from within `SomeThread::run()`. I think this may be a non-problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of synchronization, and as the handler function has a static prototype, I'd say you may need to encapsulate that synchronization inside a function, this may be a lambda for example. For synchronization, using futures may be a viable idea. If you have a pair of promise p and future f available, this boils down to:

```
socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                        [&p](/* insert args */){ p.set_value(/*value*/);});
```

and

```
while(1)
{
    auto status = f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if (status == future_status::ready)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You may need to pay attention to the validity of p, as if p's scope is the function and you're breaking out of the loop without awaiting any response, the lambda may have been called already and p may be used after leaving the function.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why one should prefer this approach over using Boost.Asio's [first class support for futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html)?